# What quantifies a stable parameter?

Tags: time-series, standard-deviation, optimization, descriptive-statistics

I'm optimizing 5 parameters for an option pricing model. Now I want to asses whether these parameters are stable over time (i.e., a year). For this I create about 12 subsamples and estimate the optimal parameters for each subsample (I do this by minimizing a cost function, i.e., chi-squared, under a certain threshold).

Now I'm not really sure what statistic quantifies those estimated parameters as stable. Is it a low standard deviation? What would be the best way to prove those parameters are stable over time?

**EDIT:** The model which I'm using is neither differentiable nor is it continuous.

Related question, without an answer: [How to test stability/variability of statistic over time, using R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62045/how-to-test-stability-variability-of-statistic-over-time-using-r)

Answer (score 1):

Google "parameter constancy test". There's a bunch of them, among most popular ones are Chow tests. There's a [paper by Ericsson](http://www.federalreserve.gov/pubs/ifdp/1991/412/default.htm) from FRB where he explains how they are used.

Comment: thanks for the pointers. I have a follow up question: is a chow test also applicable if the optimization isn't based on a linear regression, but rather on a stochastic process which is then evaluated using Monte Carlo?

Comment: Show us an example. Estimation technique is not so important as the model specification

Comment: I'm following broadie and kaya: http://finmath.stanford.edu/seminars/documents/Broadie.pdf I'm basically using a euler discretization outlined in section 2.2. however I estimate the parameters with a differential evolution algorithm (by price & storn), using a chi squared goodness of fit test.